# PHP Mobile Detect Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, class

Im using [Serbanghita's PHP Mobile Detect](https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect) class in a Wordpress install. I have the following inside my header.php file:

```
<?php
include 'php/Mobile_Detect.php';
$detect = new Mobile_Detect();
?>
```

When I place the following inside my single.php file I get a call on a non-object error:

```
<?php if ($detect->isMobile()) {
       //Do something
} ?>
```

Any ideas? I can't move the include to my single.php file because I need to use it in header.php and of course I cant copy it into the single.php file because then Im redclaring the class.

Any help, much appreciated.

Comment: instead you can use this wordpress built in function  wp is mobile http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_is_mobile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $detect variable is not available in the scope of the file single.php.

Either use **global $detect** or first define $detect by calling **$detect = new Mobile_Detect();**

All though I should warn you that polluting the global scope is very prone to bugs and strongly discouraged. At least try to minimise the amount of global variables (eg. wrap functionality in a class?), use an unique name (eg. prefix it) or even better use advanced techniques like factory class.

Comment: Answer was to first make $detect a global variable (for use in all the various php files).

<?php
include 'php/Mobile_Detect.php';
global $detect;
$detect = new Mobile_Detect();
?>

Comment: then add `<?php global $detect ?>` top of the sub templates... Also note there is a wordpress plugin too http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-mobile-detect/